# Dotnet restore from local folder Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2, dotnet-cli, .net-core

I want to restore from a local folder.  I tried

```
dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config
```

(with configuration local folder), but it still download to C:/Windows10/User/Me/.nuget/packages.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what is Package Restore Feed and Package Folder. From [NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) doc:

> Package Restore feature will install all referenced packages before a project is built, thereby ensuring that all dependencies are available to a project without requiring them to be stored in source control ... Packages are put into a packages folder.

When you add the local source, you only specify the additional package feed for package restoring. If you want to modify Package Folder, you may modify [repositoryPath](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings) in Nuget.config:

> Allows you to install the NuGet packages in the specified folder, instead of the default "$(Solutiondir)\Packages" folder.

```
<settings>
    <repositoryPath> specify_here_your_local_path </repositoryPath>
</settings>
```